# How to add <i> item if menu has sub-menu into wp_nav_menu

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I have this type of menu, and I want this menu to convert into wp_nav_menu

```
<li><a href="#">menu ab</a></li>                                
<li ><a href="#">menu bc<i class="hover-ind fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="#">sub menu ab</a></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see if menu have submenu then I have to add `<i></i>` code snippets to show down arrow with particular menu.

So I am trying, if menu has sub menu then add `<i></i>` with anchor link into `li`.

I am able to add attributes to `li` if menu has submenu by this code:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'wpse154485_add_aria_haspopup_atts', 10, 3 );
function wpse154485_add_aria_haspopup_atts( $atts, $item, $args ) {
  if (in_array('menu-item-has-children', $item->classes)) {
    $atts['aria-haspopup'] = 'true';
  }
  return $atts;
}
```

but I need add a `<i></i>` code snippet if menu has submenu, Please help if anyone have clue about it.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue. May be if someone looking for answer in future then my solution can help them. here is I found a blog which is exactly for the solution for drop down indicator.
http://dksolution.in/add-dropdown-arrow-indicators-to-wordpress-menu-items-that-have-submenus/

Answer (score 0):

you need to modify the `Walker_Nav_Menu` for adding your HTML markup.
check the GitHub link below for sample code.

https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker

Comment: Thanks @Niloy but I found the solution somewhere else.